What are the rules for two or many verb subject-verb agreement?

During lunch, the teacher in the school grades papers or talks about plan for the weekend.

Subject is the teacher. Here verbs are grade and talk followed by or. So my question is: only the 1st verb follow the subject or both follow the subject?

"talks about plans [OR] their plan for the weekend.  The noun "plan" needs a determiner.

Edit
We expand the sentence and use plans:

During lunch, the teacher in the school grades papers or [the teacher] talks about plans for the weekend.

The second verb has to agree with the subject too, and hence we use talks.
